# Multiple commands in Symfony Process Component

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to execute multiple commands using Symfony Process Component but second command is not being processed. What am I doing wrong?

```
        $process = new Process('sshpass -p password ssh user@host');
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        echo $process->getOutput();

        $process1 = new Process("sudo reboot -f");
        $process1->run();
        if (!$process1->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process1);
        }
        echo $process1->getOutput();
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Process are isolated, the second will not be executed inside the ssh session you open at the top of your code.

You must use only one process todo that.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve my desired result with this `$process = new Process('sshpass -p password ssh user@host sudo reboot -f');` .

Comment: This is right, but how to run multiple command with Symfony Process inside the same controller?

Comment: This really not answers the question. Its more like pointing the finger to someone and saying "what you doing is wrong" ! At leaste there is no sample that shows the correct way!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you run multiple commands with [symfony process](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/process.html)

```
$process = new Process('sshpass -p password ssh user@host');
$process->run();                            //Run the command (whole process)

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {            //Executes after the command finishes
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();                 //Output the result (optional)

$process->setCommandLine('sudo reboot -f'); //Set a new Command to the current process
$process->run();                            //Run this process again

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {            //Executes after the command finishes
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();                 //Next output (also optional)
```

As stated in the comments, `setCommandLine` method has been removed in symfony 5. So this solution works only for symfony <= 4.4 (latest symfony 4 version)

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore because the setCommandLine() method has been removed.

Comment: @fred Thanks for mentioning this. I updated my answere. There were no symfony 5 in '18 :)